# Same loading code fails or succeeds depending on from where you run it?

Tags: ruby

Could you, please, clarify this sentence for me from "The Ruby Programming Language" by Flanagan and Matsumoto: "If the file to load is specified with an absolute path, or is relative to ~ (the user’s home directory), then that specific file is loaded."
Following this idea I tried to load the ~/loadee.rb from the ~/projects/loader.rb since "the file to load ... is relative to ~". 
~/projects/loader.rb contains:

```
puts "First line in ~/projects/loader.rb"
load 'loadee.rb'
puts "Back to ~/projects/loader.rb"
```

loadee.rb contains:

```
puts "Contributed by ~/loadee.rb"
```

My question is why it fails with an error "cannot load such file -- loadee.rb" when I run it like this:

```
~/projects$ ruby loader.rb
```

Besides, I found out that even without changing anything in the file loading succeeds if you run it like this:

```
~$ ruby projects/loader.rb
```

Other questions that I looked through on that subject did not make it clear. And they are heavily cluttered with addressing to how it corresponds to same technique in other languages like C. Ruby is my first language and I would be more puzzled by such overviews of other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Because Ruby doesn't refer from the current path but rather from Ruby's [`$LOAD_PATH`](https://thoughtbot.com/blog/following-the-path):

```
irb(main)> $LOAD_PATH
```

so probably, the `~/projects` path is registered to `$LOAD_PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. It is not so easy as it may seem.

First of, ruby goes to see if the loadee.rb is in the same directory as loader.rb. If it is a load method followed by a bare name plus dot plus extension will suffice. But you may as well provide an absolute path.

Secondly, loadee.rb may be in the directory other than that of a loader.rb. In this case the call to load takes an argument in the form of a relative path.

And, thirdly, loadee.rb can be loaded even if it resides in the different folder than that of a loader.rb and you didn't provide a relative path - only a bare file name plus dot plus rb extension. But to do this you have to switch to the directory in which loadee.rb resides and make it your current working directory. This way ruby will pick it up and use it. 
There's one thing to note, however. You can easily steer ruby away from this scenario if you overprovide it. Namely, if you do both: provide a relative path and make loadee.rb's directory your current working directory in the terminal the whole thing will fail to load.

Comment: Please don't use answers to write summaries, unless you intend it to be the selected solution. IF that is your purpose, please provide some examples of what you mean. Also, since SO is not a message board or forum, please use proper grammar. Capitalization is important: "ruby" -> "Ruby"